# MySQL not fetching all results

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to fetch all results in `PHP` from `MySQL` database, but it is leaving the first query.

My `MySQL` table is in the below image: [image].

My Code:

```
<?php
    $irn = "33857";
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE Inv = :inv ORDER BY Sr ASC ');
    $stmt->bindParam(':inv',$irn);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowc = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    ?>
<table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
      <h1>Company</br><span style="font-size: 75%;">Number</span></h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: left;"><?php echo $rowc['Customer']; ?>&nbsp;(<?php echo $rowc['Inv']; ?>)</span></h3>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: right;"><?php echo $rowc['Date']; ?></span></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            $i++;

?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $Item; ?></td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo getIndianCurrency(225); ?>Only</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td><strong>225</strong></td>
    </tr>

</table>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

The result when I execute the above code is in the below image: [image]

There are **three** queries with `invoice` number **33857**, but only **two** are displayed (leaving the first one)!

I need all to be displayed as per `invoice` number.

Please help me from sorting out the error/code I made or I left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is with the line:

```
$rowc = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in the beginning of your code you're fetching the first row.

You have to update your while loop, like this

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
        while($rowc)
        {
            extract($rowc);
            $i++;

?>

<!-- Your HTML/PHP code for the table -->

<?php 
           $rowc=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
?>
```

So, the idea is to fetch the row at the end of the while loop, in order to not lose your first row.

Comment: Removing that, I also have to change `<?php echo $rowc['Customer']; ?>`. So what will be the edited code for `<?php echo $rowc['Customer']; ?>` ?

Comment: @BTC Yes, I have noticed it right now. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks for answering